# How can we restricted accessing redis from only certain IPs?

Tags: asp.net, redis

I have implemented redis server 3.0 I have specific scenario that my two server is only going to be use this redis server so is there any setting in config file that I allow only two IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami pointed out, there is no builtin system to restrict IP addresses but you may want to see the [AUTH](http://redis.io/commands/auth) command in redis to authenticate clients.

Use [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to restrict access to the machine hosting redis.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use firewall to restrict access to redis. It has no in-built IP restriction system in place to help with this.